# Trying to count names across multiple rows for work scheduling purposes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet that looks something like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| shift  | Staff1 | Staff2 | Staff3 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2hours | john   | bob    | smith  |
| 3hours | dave   | jose   | mike   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

So basically i would like a way to calculate total number of hours each person works in a week. I have used the `=(countif(C2:C6,"$J3")*2)` however i have multiple rows of certain hour shifts for each day of the week. I was looking for a way to condense it all as much as possible so my equation wasn't a mile long.

Comment: Have you tried using a Pivot table?

Comment: I have tried. I need the pivot table to calculate frequency of names and to assign a value to it depending on the names location in the sheet. 
Basically I am using this excel sheet to schedule my employees. I have a variety of shifts each day of the week and these shifts are organized by the hours they take up. What I want to calculate is each individual employees total hours in a given week.So my data is names and not numbers and I have no idea how to organize it so that the pivot table understand that if a name is in a certain row then that means the person has worked a number of hours.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In to "Unpivot" your sheet into a new Table layout with less columns and more rows.  This would be ideal for analysing with a Pivot Table.

Here's a description of the Power Query "Unpivot" command:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/unpivot-columns-HA104053356.aspx

I would aim to Unpivot the data to produce an Excel table looking something like:

`+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| shift  | Hours  | Staff  | Name   | 
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2hours | 2      | Staff1 | john   | 
| 2hours | 2      | Staff2 | bob    | 
| 2hours | 2      | Staff3 | smith  | 
| 3hours | 3      | Staff1 | dave   | 
| 3hours | 3      | Staff2 | jose   | 
| 3hours | 3      | Staff3 | mike   | 
+--------+--------+--------+--------+`

I would use the Power Query Split command to get the Hours column as a number.  Then you can sum that in the Pivot Table.

The Staff column may be meaningless - it depends on whether your assignments to Staff1/2/3 have any meaning.